# Serving index.html at root context with embedded Jetty

Tags: java, jetty

With the following code I am able to serve up my views at / as well as my REST API at /rest. Currently, I am not using a web.xml.

Can I serve /index.html at / using Jetty or without defining a web.xml? (This is part of a framework I'm building - I'd like to avoid file generation if possible).

```
protected RESTServer(int port, Class<?> api, String path) {
        // Server
        this.server = new org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server(port);

        // REST
        ServletContextHandler restHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        restHandler.setContextPath(path);

        ServletHolder servlet = restHandler.addServlet(ServletContainer.class, "/rest/*");
        servlet.setInitOrder(0);
        servlet.setInitParameter(JERSEY_PROVIDER, api.getCanonicalName());

         // Web
        ResourceHandler webHandler = new ResourceHandler();
        webHandler.setDirectoriesListed(true);
        webHandler.setResourceBase("src/main/webapp");
        webHandler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{"index.html"});

        // Server
        HandlerCollection handlers = new HandlerCollection();
        handlers.addHandler(webHandler);
        handlers.addHandler(restHandler);
        server.setHandler(handlers);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with. It requires the Jetty webapp dependency.

```
protected RESTServer(int port, Class<?> api, String path) {
        this.server = new org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server(port);
        WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
        webAppContext.setResourceBase("src/main/webapp");
        ServletHolder restServlet = webAppContext.addServlet(ServletContainer.class, "/rest/*");
        restServlet.setInitOrder(0);
        restServlet.setInitParameter(JERSEY_PROVIDER, api.getCanonicalName());
        HandlerCollection handlers = new HandlerCollection();
        handlers.addHandler(webAppContext);
        server.setHandler(handlers);
}
```